# How to fix the width of a webpage?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I have completed the development of a webpage. I have made it responsive for mobile phones using media queries. Now my concern is that for mobile screen sizes and laptop screen sizes the page is good but when we go to big screen sizes like monitors or TVs the page gets clumsy. I want to fix the width of the entire page to 1536 Pixels so that even on the big screen sizes the page of the width remains the same and all my content above 1536 Pixel screen sizes should look the same as it's looking on the 1536 Pixel screen size. As the page is already developed please provide a solution that I can just apply in the body tag and it gets applied on the entire page.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `max-width` ? did you try it ?

Comment: I tried now, it worked :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add a max-width and margin auto (this ensures the page is centered) to the body wrapper something like this example (keep in mind your main wrapper may be using a different class)

```
.body-wrapper {
  max-width: 1220px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image]